# UDP Packet loss at Sender

Tags: udp, packet-loss

I have an application that sends logs to a log server residing on a different machine. These logs are sent as UDP packets. My problem is that i see UDP log loss. I have a running sequence number in the UDP packets which is printed along with the log message. I saw gaps in the sequence numbers at the log server. At first i suspected my log server to be the culprit but looks like the problem is at the sender machine dropping packets. The environment is:
Both sender and receiver running on HP G8 servers with CentOS 6.4 (2.6.32-358.el6.i686). Here are the things that I have already tried or observed:

1. The SndbufErrors and RcvbufErrors are 0 both on sender and receiver (/proc/net/snmp)
2. The ifconfig does not show any errors
3. The switch to which these machines are connected does not report any drops/erros
4. Running tcpdump on the sender side (with increased buffer for tcpdump so that the tcpdump reports 0 packets dropped) reveals that the packets missed by the receiver are infact not sent (or at least those packets does not show up on the captupred pcaps)
5. The maximum rate of the packet's sent is around 30K per second (the rate is not constant. normally it stays at very low around 500 per second with occasional spikes. The packets are lost during these spikes). The interface is 100Mbps link.
6. The size of the packet varies from around 80 bytes to 300 bytes.
7. The ring buffer on the NICs are:
   Ring parameters for eth0:
   Pre-set maximums:
   RX:             2047
   RX Mini:        0
   RX Jumbo:       0
   TX:             511
   Current hardware settings:
   RX:             200
   RX Mini:        0
   RX Jumbo:       0
   TX:             511
8. NIC driver info:
   driver: tg3
   version: 3.124
   firmware-version: 5719-v1.38 NCSI v1.2.37.0
   bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
   supports-statistics: yes
   supports-test: yes
   supports-eeprom-access: yes
   supports-register-dump: yes
   supports-priv-flags: no
9. The NIC stats also shows no errors (throug ethtool -S eth0)
10. If i run my log server on the same machine as sender, there is no log loss.

I am clueless as where these packets are getting dropped (stack/NIC/NW...). I know UDP is un-reliable and packets can be dropped due to multiple reasons. But I am not still not able to find that reason as to why these packets are being dropped in my case at the sender side. On a different sidenote my application has also many TCP connections (around 8-10) with traffic on each connection.

Comment: Can you show the udp-sending portion of the code?

Comment: Please see the UDP side code. Nothing special abput it tho `sockFd =::socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);   setsockopt(sockFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sendBufSize, Len); ` the sendBufSize is 8MB. `::sendto (sockFd, message, totalLength, 0, dest,
                sizeof (::sockaddr_in));`

Comment: I presume you check all your sends and everything "obvious"?

Comment: I am checking the return value of sendto and in case of -1 i am logging that locally into a temp file. Unfortunately i dont see any errors in the sendto as well.